# XML puzzle - why the null element?

Tags: c#, xml

can anyone tell me why, given the following XDocument contents

```
<AddOrderResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorMessage xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.Intertek.LIMSService">, Fehler in der Belegerfassung Verkauf
Die Kontokorrentdaten konnten nicht gelesen werden.
(Exception of type 'Sagede.OfficeLine.Wawi.BelegEngine.RecordsetEmptyException' was thrown.)</ErrorMessage>
</AddOrderResult>
```

and the following C# code

```
    var resultElement =xmlResponse.Element("AddOrderResult");
    var errorMessage = resultElement.Element("ErrorMessage");
```

where *xmlResponse* is the XDocument object in question, *resultElement*  is a valid XElement but *errorMessage* is always null? Is it, for example, something to do with the ErrorMessage namespace?

TIA.

Comment: Can you show how you are parsing the XML?

Comment: XDocument.Parse(theXMLString);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the namespace for ErrorMessage - it's different than the root XMLNS, and needs to be specified.  This code will get your element correctly:

```
string rawXmlString = @"<AddOrderResult xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <ErrorMessage xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.Intertek.LIMSService"">, Fehler in der Belegerfassung Verkauf
Die Kontokorrentdaten konnten nicht gelesen werden.
(Exception of type 'Sagede.OfficeLine.Wawi.BelegEngine.RecordsetEmptyException' was thrown.)
  </ErrorMessage>
</AddOrderResult>";

XDocument xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(rawXmlString);

var resultElement =xmlResponse.Element("AddOrderResult");
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.Intertek.LIMSService";
var errorMessage = resultElement.Element(ns + "ErrorMessage");
```

You could also get it without the namespace, but it's a bit more clunky...

```
var errorMessage_NoNS = resultElement.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ErrorMessage").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that approach. I wondered if the different namespace was culpable.

Comment: The non-clunky approach, I meant. Solved the problem at a stroke. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear - the clunky approach was added later as an afterthought, in case you have to deal with this a lot and don't always know the namespace ahead of time.